# Trouble setting up reliable DMA transfer between 2 TSI148 VMEbus controllers

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, vxworks, dma

I am seeking help, most importantly from VMEbus experts.

I am working on a project that aims to setup a communication channel from a real-time powerpc controller (Emerson MVME4100), running vxWorks 6.8, to a Linux Intel computer (Xembedded XVME6300), running Debian 6 with kernel 2.6.32.
This channel runs over VME bus; both computers are in a VME enclosure and both use the Tundra Tsi148 chipset. The Intel computer is explicitly configured as the system controller, the real-time computer is explicitly not.

Setup:
For the Intel computer I wrote a custom driver that creates a 4MB kernel buffer, and shares it over the VME bus by means of a slave window;
For the real-time computer I setup a DMA transfer to repeatedly forward blocks of exactly 48640 bytes; filled with bytes of test data (zeros, ones, twos, etc), in quick succession (once every 32 milliseconds, if possible)
For the Intel computer I read the kernel buffer from the driver, to see whether the data arrives correctly, with a hand-started Python program.

Expectation:
I am expecting to see the same data (zeros, ones etc) from the Python program.
I am expecting transmission times roughly corresponding to the chosen bus speed (typically 290 us or 145 us, depending on bus speed), plus a reasonable DMA setup overhead (up to 10us? I am willing to accept larger numbers, say hundreds of usecs, if that is what the bus *normally* needs)

Result:

- Sometimes data does not arrive at all, and "transmission" time is ~2000 us
- Sometimes data arrives reliably, but transmission time is ~98270us, or 98470us, depending on the chosen bus speed.

Questions:
How could I make the transmission reliable and bring down these aweful latencies?
What general direction should I search next?

(I would like to tag with VMEbus if I could)

Many thanks

Comment: I found that 98470 us was due to an invalid setting at the real-time computer. I used a modification of example VME DMA transfer where I tried to let the tsi148 use a block size of 8192 bytes and a holdoff value of 64us between each two blocks. The blocksize of 8192 is an invalid value which the code translated in such a way that it effectively became 32bytes, thus accounting for roughly 97 of the 98 milliseconds latency.

Comment: Failure to forward data with "latencies" of ~2000us was found to be a mismatch in speeds and endoding on the VME backplane. If a DMA transaction of 2eSST320 tries to talk to a window configured to 2eSST160, the transaction fails and the routine takes about this much time to discover the failure.

Comment: Martijn, I don't know anything about this topic, I just wanted to compliment you for the well-worded and thorough question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comments on the question describe how I got the bus working:
- ensure 2eSST320 on both sides of the bus
- ensure that the DMA transaction used a valid block size (the largest valid was 4096 bytes)

I achieved an effective speed of 150MBytes/s (the bus can achieve 320MBytes/s but the tsi148 chip is known for causing significant overhead). This is good enough for me.